# After submit, b(array_name).map is not a function - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have started learning ReactJS and I am stuck on this error for a while now.

```
export default class Bag extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        books : [
            {
                name : "Origin",
                read : "Yes",
                owner: "Yes"
            },
            {
                name: "The Alchemist",
                read: "Yes",
                owner: "Yes"
            },
            {
                name : "The Tale of Twisted Candle",
                read : "Yes",
                owner: "Yes"
            },
            {
                name: "Martian",
                read: "Yes",
                owner: "Yes"
            }
        ]
    }
    this.setStateHandler = this.setStateHandler.bind(this)
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
}


setStateHandler(){
    this.setState({books: this.state.books })
}

handleChange(book){
    console.log("Here is your book:")
    console.log(book)
    console.log(this.state.books)
    let tempVal = {
        name : book.name,
        read : book.read,
        owner: book.owner 
    }
    this.setState({books: this.state.books.push(tempVal) })
    console.log(this.state.books)
}

render(){
    let b = this.state.books
    return (
        <div align="center">
            <h1>{this.props.name}'s Bag</h1>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>Book Name</th>
                    <th>Read</th>
                    <th>Ownership</th>
                </tr>
                </tbody>

                <tbody>
                    { b.map(function(book){
                        return <Book name={book.name} read={book.read} owner={book.owner}/>
                    })}
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <BookForm name="Book" read="No" owner="No" onChange={this.handleChange} />
            <Button />    
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

When code is run for first time, everything works fine. But when I try to submit a new book, an error is thrown.

*TypeError: b.map is not a function*

While looking for the solution in other similar questions, they all referred that the map function is for Array not Object. So, I have checked that too. Apparently, the new value of 'b' after submit is still an Array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line:

```
this.setState({books: this.state.books.push(tempVal) })
```

in your `handleChange` method is likely the problem. The `push` method returns a number, so that line is actually setting the value of `books` in your state to a number, not an array. You might try changing it to:

```
this.setState({books: this.state.books.concat([tempVal]) })
```

Or, if you want to use the functional `setState` style:

```
this.setState(prevState => {
    prevState.books.push(tempVal);
    return prevState;
});
```

Comment: Thank you @CRice for your help. Now, it is running successfully.